# "Collection not found for module path: mzscheme" in Racket when running Arc

Tags: racket, arc-lisp

I'm trying to get Arc (the Lisp dialect by Paul Graham) to run on my iMac running macOS Catalina, I downloaded the arc source code and installed Racket. I followed some of the tips at the question [Installing Arc on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488718/installing-arc-on-os-x) to fix some problems I was having, but now I'm getting this error message when I run "racket -f as.scm":

```
standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  for module path: mzscheme
  collection: "mzscheme"
  in collection directories:
   /Users/mikkel/Library/Racket/7.8/collects
   /usr/local/Cellar/minimal-racket/7.8/share/racket/collects
   /usr/local/Cellar/minimal-racket/7.8/share/racket/pkgs/racket-lib
  context...:
   show-collection-err
   standard-module-name-resolver
   module-path-index-resolve
   perform-require!
   for-loop
   expand-capturing-lifts
   temp98_0
   temp71_0
   compile
   temp65_0
   loop
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a fix, so I'm not posting it as an answer, but it looks like you might not have the mzscheme package for racket. Try `raco pkg install mzscheme`.